# pop up table using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i m trying to make a pop up table which happens next to the biggest div that i have(right side) when the user clicks on the white button. But i m kinda out of ideas about how to do it. Is there any way to do it with bootstrap? If not still any tipps would be greatly appreciated !
https://jsfiddle.net/e97ut32r/

```
<div id ="a">
    <div id ="b"></div>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

```js
#a {       
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding: 10px 40px; 
    background: #dddddd;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
#b {
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 10%;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
button{
    margin-left: 1cm;
    margin-top: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modals, basically is an overall div where you can put any kind of content.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: but the problem is how can i make it exactly right next to my biggest div with size and width which i want ? sorry a totall newbie here..